# Skip lines based on condition MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, scanf

When reading a text file in MATLAB I use:

```
file = fopen(filename, 'r');
formatSpec = '%d %d %d %d';
A = fscanf(file, formatSpec, [4 Inf]);
```

Not every line meets the formatSpec and can contain error messages. Now Matlab will just stop at lines which do not correspond to the aforementioned format.

How do I skip all lines which cannot be matched by the formatSpec?

So an input file looking like this:

```
04 2 1 312
04 2 2 212
04 error
05 2 1 421
```

Should give me the following matrix:

```
 04  04  05
  2   2   2
  1   2   1
312 212 421
```

Comment: Look at the [`textscan`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) command instead of `fscanf` and try to play with the `'EmptyValue'` and `'TreatAsEmpty'` parameters of the function.

Comment: Although not really an answer to your question, consider pre-processing your input file using `grep` or `awk`. This has worked well for me in the past - if your data file is large then processing text on input in MATBLAB can have a significant performance implication (which may or may not be important to your application) so then it is simpler to just ensure that all the data is clean to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your answers I will look into textscan. Since I am not very good at using grep/awk I hoped to do this in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

this should work for your example.
It reads a line, splits it by spaces and checks whether all elements are integers (this can be changed to double or else). If there is a string the line is skipped else it writes the elements to your matrix and fills the rest with NaN. The latter is only for the case you have different numbers of elements per line... 
Just make sure that linemax is larger than the number of lines in your data file and elementsmax is larger than the number of elements per line.

```
clear all
fclose all;
filename = 'text_test.dat';

file = fopen(filename, 'r');
linemax     = 1000;
elementsmax = 100;
A = zeros(linemax,elementsmax);
line = 1;
real_elementsmax = 1;
while (feof(file) == 0 && line < linemax)       % read until the end of the file is reached
    linetext = fgetl(file); %read frst line of the file
    text_array=regexp(linetext,' ','split');
    if min(isint(str2double(text_array)))
        nelements = size(text_array,2);
        A(line,1:nelements) = str2double(text_array(1:nelements));
        A(line,nelements+1:elementsmax) = NaN;
        line = line+1;
        real_elementsmax = max(real_elementsmax,nelements);
    end
end
fclose(file);
A(line:linemax,:)=[];
A(:,real_elementsmax+1:elementsmax)=[];
```

Comment: The reason I used fscanf with the [4 Inf] formating parameter was because I cannot know the size of the file in advance

Comment: @Lukas Häfliger, this should not be a problem with the code I posted as I kept it general. You can set elementsmax to 10000 as in the end all surplus lines will get eliminated so you have the right shape. The limit would only be the memory needed for the preallocation.